# Referencing rails assets without the digest?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I am referencing assets in my rails app directly, for ex. `background-image: url('/assets/bg.png')`.
But I just realized this wouldn't work in production since digested assets are served (/assets/bg-dddasd434r4tfdfs...sada.png) in production.
Is my only choice to use helper methods (for ex, `image-url`) throughout the application or is there a more simpler solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `asset_path('app.js', :digest => false)` or disable digest in the prodution env:

```
# config/environments/prodution.rb
config.assets.digest = false
```

<sub>[Rails pipeline](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)</sub>

Comment: Thanks, I suppose I can do that but what would happen if I change a particular asset and since it has no mtime appended,I believe the client would still see the old asset. What i mean is if there is any disadvantage to disabling digest ? I think the only option is to reference them with the assets helper

Answer (score 1):

In config/application.rb change the value of

`config.assets.digest` to `false`

Answer (score 0):

This is an ancient question, but since I happened upon it with Google...

In Rails 5 there is the asset_path helper which even in the .scss files can return the proper path to a file.